# No directive found for `bcrypt`

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm following official Lighthouse documentation on how to setup GraphQl into my project.
Unfortunately, I'm stacked with the following error:

`` No directive found for `bcrypt` ``

Following schema I have created so far:

```
type Query {
    users: [User!]! @paginate(defaultCount: 10)
    user(id: ID @eq): User @find
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
}

type Mutation {
    createUser(
        name: String!,
        email: String! @rules(apply: ["email", "unique:users"])
        password: String! @bcrypt
    ): User @create
}
```

The query I'm trying to execute is following:

```
mutation {
  createUser(
    name:"John Doe"
    email:"john@test.com"
    password: "somesupersecret"
  ) {
    id
    email
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay dug up - there is no more `@brypt` directory in \vendor\nuwave\lighthouse\src\Schema\Directives\ instead, there is `@hash` directive which is working like a charm and uses driver you specify in `config/hashing.php` configuration file